# Tensorflow: Tensor to numpy array conversion without running any session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created an OP in tensorflow where for some processing I need my data to be converted from tensor object to numpy array. I know we can use `tf.eval()` or `sess.run` to evaluate any tensor object. What I really want to know is, Is there any way to convert tensor to array without any session running, so in turn we avoid use of `.eval()` or `.run()`.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
def tensor_to_array(tensor1):
    '''Convert tensor object to numpy array'''
    array1 = SESS.run(tensor1) **#====== need to bypass this line**
    return array1.astype("uint8")

def array_to_tensor(array):
    '''Convert numpy array to tensor object'''
    tensor_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(array, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tensor_data
```

Comment: Unlikely in the general case, since you don't know the answers without running the pipeline

Comment: There must be some way out , right?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't think you are making a correct statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated**

```
# must under eagar mode
def tensor_to_array(tensor1):
    return tensor1.numpy()
```

**example**

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.enable_eager_execution()
>>> def tensor_to_array(tensor1):
...     return tensor1.numpy()
...
>>> x = tf.constant([1,2,3,4])
>>> tensor_to_array(x)
array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
```

---

I believe you can do it without `tf.eval()` or `sess.run` by using `tf.enable_eager_execution()`

**example**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
c = tf.constant([4,3,2,1])
c+x
<tf.Tensor: id=5, shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([5, 5, 5, 5], dtype=int32)>
```

For more details about tensorflow eager mode, checkout here:[Tensorflow eager](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)

**If without `tf.enable_eager_execution()`:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
c = tf.constant([4,3,2,1])
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
c+x
<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(4,) dtype=int32>
```

Comment: Hi...eager_execution looks interesing, but I don't think it serves my purpose. Please have a look at below snippet.

Comment: Can you provide the details of the tensor object that you would like to parse, please?

Comment: def tensor_to_array(tensor1):
    '''Convert tensor object to numpy array'''
    array1 = SESS.run(tensor1) #== need to replace this line ===
    return array1.astype("uint8")

def array_to_tensor(array):
    '''Convert numpy array to tensor object'''
    tensor_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(array, dtype=tf.float32) 
    return tensor_data

Comment: Updated above, please check

Comment: It throws an error : AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Are you doing it under eagar mode?

Comment: @KapB I fixed your functions and added example in the answer above.

Comment: I don't know how is it working for you. I'm using exactly same code and still it throws an error : AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'. Can you please tell me what exactly that 'numpy' does?

Comment: It was a silly mistake. I needed to upgrade tensorflow version. It seems enable_eager_execution is available in recent version. Thanks for the help @R.yan

Comment: Sorry mate, forgot to tell you to upgrade your tensorflow

Comment: @ R.yan can you confirm whether this tf.enable_eager_execution() runs session internally?

Comment: I don’t think it run session internally. Since it do the ops immediately like numpy library, it didn’t wait like normal session.

Comment: Thanks @R.yan ...Also refer this link for further information. https://towardsdatascience.com/eager-execution-tensorflow-8042128ca7be

Comment: I'm still facing an issue. If I run all the commands from anaconda prompt, I'm getting the desired output. But when I try to run it as script in spyder, it throws an error of "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'". Do you have any idea why so?? I have made sure that spyder runs from same environemnt but the problem still persists. @R.yan

Comment: Maybe its spyder problem. Cannot do much for me since I don't have much background about your code. Can you create another question and provide the details please?