# When does a tensor output a value and when does it output a tensor object?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have had some experience with creating Neural networks graphs with input as tensorflow placeholders . Until now , i used to believe that those graphs could be evaluated with something like `sess.run()` or more precisely as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow).

I was learning to see how a GAN works and came across this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX-6CMNnT64&t=279s) where the author creates a function(time 11:00 in the video) :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(7,(3,3) , padding = "same" , input_shape = (28,28,1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model
```

And then evaluates a forward pass as follows :

```
model_discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
model_discriminator(np.random.rand(1,28,28,1).astype("float32"))
```

He gets the following output :

```
<tf.Tensor: id=161  ,shape=(1,1) ,dtype=float32 , numpy=array([[0.01451516]],dtype = float32)>
```

The value `numpy=array([[0.01451516]]` is the output of the forward pass. 
On running the same code , i get a less infromative tensor which is :

```
<tf.Tensor 'sequential_5/dense_11/BiasAdd:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>
```

Is the difference due to difference version of tensorflow in the environment ? I am using `tensorflow 1.14.0` , not sure about the one used in the video.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of TF 2.0. As long as they are not a part of a function decorated with `@tf.function`, Tensors and Numpy arrays are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is because of the different versions of the tensorflow.

In **tensorflow version 1.14** the output on running **your code** is as below(have added the print of tf version),

```
tensorflow version: 1.14.0
<tf.Tensor 'sequential_3/dense_7/BiasAdd:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>
```

If you would like to extract the value in tensorflow version 1.14, then modify the code as below,

```
#!pip install tensorflow==1.14

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

print("tensorflow version:",tf.__version__)

def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(7,(3,3) , padding = "same" , input_shape = (28,28,1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model 

model_discriminator = make_discriminator_model()

#initialize the variable
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

#run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) #execute init_op
    print("Value of the model_discriminator function:",sess.run(model_discriminator(np.random.rand(1,28,28,1).astype("float32"))))
```

Output will be -

```
tensorflow version: 1.14.0
Value of the model_discriminator function: [[0.00674586]]
```

While in **tensorflow version 2.1** the output on running **your code** is as below(have added the print of tf version),

```
tensorflow version: 2.1.0
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.01521136]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: @warrior_monk - If you would like understand difference between normal tensor and symbolic tensor then you can view this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338842/how-to-print-value-of-tensorflow-python-framework-ops-tensor-in-tensorflow-2-0/60564318#60564318