# How to convert tensor to ndarray

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array

I'm beginner of tensorflow.
The **yolo_model.predict** returns tensor.But when i use cpu_nms, i need to convert **pred_boxes** and **pred_scores** to ndarray.
I have tried using **.eval ()** but I get some FailedPreconditionError.

'''

```
img = np.asarray(img, np.float32)
img = img[np.newaxis, :] / 255.

with tf.Session() as sess:

    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, args.new_size[1], args.new_size[0], 3], name='input_data')
    yolo_model = yolov3(args.num_class, args.anchors)
    with tf.variable_scope('yolov3'):
        pred_feature_maps = yolo_model.forward(input_data, False)

    pred_boxes, pred_confs, pred_probs = yolo_model.predict(pred_feature_maps)

    pred_scores = pred_confs * pred_probs
    # pred_boxes = pred_boxes.eval()
    # pred_scores = pred_scores.eval()

    boxes, scores, labels = cpu_nms(pred_boxes, pred_scores, args.num_class, max_boxes=200, score_thresh=0.3, iou_thresh=0.45)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, args.restore_path)

    boxes_, scores_, labels_ = sess.run([boxes, scores, labels], feed_dict={input_data: img})
```

'''
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the error and trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are extracting variable tensor and then to an array, then below are the example for different versions of tensorflow.

If you would like to extract the value in **tensorflow version 1.14 OR other versions that support session**, then below is an example -

```
#!pip install tensorflow==1.14

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

print("tensorflow version:",tf.__version__)

def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(7,(3,3) , padding = "same" , input_shape = (28,28,1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model 

model_discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
output = model_discriminator(np.random.rand(1,28,28,1).astype("float32"))

#initialize the variable
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

#run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) #execute init_op
    print("Output as a Tensor:",output)
    out = np.array(sess.run(output))
    print("Output as an Array:",out)
    print("Type of the Array:",type(out))
```

Output will be -

```
tensorflow version: 1.14.0
Output as a Tensor: Tensor("sequential_7/dense_15/BiasAdd:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
Output as an Array: [[-0.29746282]]
Type of the Array: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If you would like to extract the value in **tensorflow version 2.1 OR other versions that supports tensor print**, then below is an example -

```
#!pip install tensorflow==2.1

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

print("tensorflow version:",tf.__version__)

def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(7,(3,3) , padding = "same" , input_shape = (28,28,1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model 

model_discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
output = model_discriminator(np.random.rand(1,28,28,1).astype("float32"))
print("Output as a Tensor:",output)

out = np.array(output)
print("Output as an Array:",out)
print("Type of the Array:",type(out))
```

Output will be -

```
tensorflow version: 2.1.0
Output as a Tensor: tf.Tensor([[0.32392436]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
Output as an Array: [[0.32392436]]
Type of the Array: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**NOTE:** There are symbolic and variable tensor, you can understand the difference between them here - [Symbolic Tensor Vs Variable Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338842/how-to-print-value-of-tensorflow-python-framework-ops-tensor-in-tensorflow-2-0/60564318#60564318)

Comment: @Glen_Z - If I have answered your question, can you please accept and upvote it. Thank You.